# Postgresql: why "ILIKE" is case-sensitive sometimes?

Tags: postgresql

I'm searching this row:

```
"c717e4d6-8db3-4c68-8c6f-f853c6c62312", "Аристотель", "source"
```

These queries successfully finding it:

```
SELECT id, name, type FROM amt WHERE owner = '802f11da-c41c-4ad0-ae15-c7cf734c807f' AND name LIKE '%Ари%' limit 5;
SELECT id, name, type FROM amt WHERE owner = '802f11da-c41c-4ad0-ae15-c7cf734c807f' AND name ILIKE '%Ари%' limit 5;
```

This one does NOT finding it:

```
SELECT id, name, type FROM amt WHERE owner = '802f11da-c41c-4ad0-ae15-c7cf734c807f' AND name ILIKE '%ари%' limit 5;
```

As you see, the difference between 2nd and 3rd query is only one letter: "Ари" vs "ари".

Usually, `ILIKE` works as expected, but in some cases it just can't properly search. I have no idea why it happens.

SQL pane from current database:

```
CREATE DATABASE v_2_prod
  WITH OWNER = postgres
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = pg_default
       LC_COLLATE = 'C'
       LC_CTYPE = 'C'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

Comment: I am not seeing this behavior with PostgreSQL 9.3 (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f96626/5). In this SQLFiddle I have just modified your query a little bit to work with an example targeting the test case you have noticed. `ILIKE` appears to be providing correct results. I suspect something in the locale may lead to this behavior (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/locale.html)

Comment: How is that database encoded? If it's encoded incorrectly `ILIKE` won't know that `А` (U+0410) is an uppercase `а` (U+0430).

Comment: @Schwern, Thank you for suggestion. How can i check if it's encoded correctly?

Comment: @Schwern you was right. Take a look at the addon at the end of my question. I had to put 'en_US.UTF-8' instead of 'C' in `LC_COLLATE` and `LC_CTYPE`

Comment: Have you tried Russian locale settings, e. g. `ru_RU.UTF-8` for `LC_COLLATE` and `LC_TYPE`? Newer postgres versions have a better collation support, too: `UPPER(name COLLATE "ru_RU.UTF-8")`.

Comment: See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/collation.html for details.